# Attempting to replicate Python's string interning functionality for non-strings

Tags: python, python-2.7

For a self-project, I wanted to do something like:

```
class Species(object): # immutable.
    def __init__(self, id):
        # ... (using id to obtain height and other data from file)
    def height(self):
        # ...

class Animal(object): # mutable.

    def __init__(self, nickname, species_id):
        self.nickname = nickname
        self.species = Species(id)
    def height(self):
        return self.species.height()
```

As you can see, I don't really need more than one instance of Species(id) per id, but I'd be creating one every time I'm creating an Animal object with that id, and I'd probably need multiple calls of, say, `Animal(somename, 3)`.

To solve that, what I'm trying to do is to make a class so that for 2 instances of it, let's say a and b, the following is always true:

```
(a == b) == (a is b)
```

This is something that Python does with string literals and is called **internship**. Example:

```
a = "hello"
b = "hello"
print(a is b)
```

that print will yield true (as long as the string is short enough if we're using the python shell directly).

I can only guess how CPython does this (it probably involves some C magic) so I'm doing my own version of it. So far I've got:

```
class MyClass(object):

    myHash = {} # This replicates the intern pool.

    def __new__(cls, n): # The default new method returns a new instance
        if n in MyClass.myHash:
            return MyClass.myHash[n]

        self = super(MyClass, cls).__new__(cls)
        self.__init(n)
        MyClass.myHash[n] = self

        return self

    # as pointed out on an answer, it's better to avoid initializating the instance 
    # with __init__, as that one's called even when returning an old instance.
    def __init(self, n): 
        self.n = n

a = MyClass(2)
b = MyClass(2)

print a is b # <<< True
```

My questions are:

a) Is my problem even worth solving? Since my intended Species object should be quite light weight and the max amount of times Animal can be called, rather limited (imagine a Pokemon game: no more than 1000 instances, tops)

b) If it is, is this a valid approach to solve my problem?

c) If it's not valid, could you please elaborate on a simpler / cleaner / more Pythonic way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, implementing a `__new__` method that returns a cached object is the appropriate way of creating a limited number of instances. If you don't expect to be creating a lot of instances, you could just implement `__eq__` and compare by value rather than identity, but it doesn't hurt to do it this way instead.

Note that an immutable object should generally do all its initialization in `__new__`, rather than `__init__`, since the latter is called after the object has been created. Further, `__init__` will be called on any instance of the class that is returned from `__new__`, so with when you're caching, it will be called again each time a cached object is returned.

Also, the first argument to `__new__` is the class object not an instance, so you probably should name it `cls` rather than `self` (you can use `self` instead of `instance` later in the method if you want though!).

Answer (score 2):

To make this as general as possible, I'm going to recommend a couple things. One, inherit from a `namedtuple` if you want "true" immutability (normally people are rather hands off about this, but when you're doing interning, breaking the immutable invariant can cause much bigger problems). Second, use locks to allow thread safe behavior.

Because this is rather complex, I'm going to provide a modified copy of `Species` code with comments explaining it:

```
import collections
import operator
import threading

# Inheriting from a namedtuple is a convenient way to get immutability
class Species(collections.namedtuple('SpeciesBase', 'species_id height ...')):
    __slots__ = ()  # Prevent creation of arbitrary values on instances; true immutability of declared values from namedtuple makes true immutable instances

    # Lock and cache, with underscore prefixes to indicate they're internal details
    _cache_lock = threading.Lock()
    _cache = {} 

    def __new__(cls, species_id):  # Switching to canonical name cls for class type
        # Do quick fail fast check that ID is in fact an int/long
        # If it's int-like, this will force conversion to true int/long
        # and minimize risk of incompatible hash/equality checks in dict
        # lookup
        # I suspect that in CPython, this would actually remove the need
        # for the _cache_lock due to the GIL protecting you at the
        # critical stages (because no byte code is executing comparing
        # or hashing built-in int/long types), but the lock is a good idea
        # for correctness (avoiding reliance on implementation details)
        # and should cost little
        species_id = operator.index(species_id)

        # Lock when checking/mutating cache to make it thread safe
        try:
            with cls._cache_lock:
                return cls._cache[species_id]
        except KeyError:
            pass

        # Read in data here; not done under lock on assumption this might
        # be expensive and other Species (that already exist) might be
        # created/retrieved from cache during this time
        species_id = ...
        height = ...
        # Pass all the values read to the superclass (the namedtuple base)
        # constructor (which will set them and leave them immutable thereafter)
        self = super(Species, cls).__new__(cls, species_id, height, ...)

        with cls._cache_lock:
            # If someone tried to create the same species and raced
            # ahead of us, use their version, not ours to ensure uniqueness
            # If no one raced us, this will put our new object in the cache
            self = cls._cache.setdefault(species_id, self)
        return self
```

If you want to do interning for general libraries (where users might be threaded, and you can't trust them not to break the immutability invariant), something like the above is a basic structure to work with. It's fast, minimizes the opportunity for stalls even if construction is heavyweight (in exchange for possibly reconstructing an object more than once and throwing away all but one copy if many threads try to construct it for the first time at once), etc.

Of course, if construction is cheap and instances are small, then just write a `__eq__` (and possibly `__hash__` if it's logically immutable) and be done with it.

Comment: You can see a quite similar sort of code in Python's implementation of the various [`wrapper`s for `functools.lru_cache`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/functools.py#l453). As it happens, they don't lock for the "atomic" operations when the work done is atomic, which supports my comment above, but they use the same "try to get from cache with lock, if failed, release lock, perform expensive work, reacquire lock and update cache if not raced" pattern I used above for the cache size is limited (and groups of operations must be performed atomically).